# Does moving files to Glacier lead to new uploads using sync in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

currently I am backing up data to AWS S3 using cli sync command. I´d like to make use of AWS Glacier. The idea is to backup data to S3 and move this data to Glacier based on lifecycle rules. However, I am wondering if a S3 sync still works after files have been moved to Glacier by these rules or if these files would be uploaded again to S3. Any information or experiences on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work fine.

The sync process works on filesize and modified date. These remain the same regardless of storage class.

You can now upload directly to the Glacier storage class without needing a lifecycle policy, which is ideal for backup-type files that you know you will rarely access. Just use: `--storage-class glacier`